# Why did Optimus Prime order Sam to 'push the cube into me' - instead of using it as a weapon against Megatron?

Tags: transformers, transformers-2007

Simple question. In the first Michael Bay *Transformers* film, why did Optimus Prime tell Sam Witwicky to push the cube into Prime's chest - instead of just attacking Megatron with it?

And also why did Sam choose to ignore his command? Sam had no idea what it would do if it entered Megatron's body, for all he knew it could have given him a massive power boost.

Comment: It's Michael Bay.  You were expecting logic?  Bigger explosion this way!

Comment: I think somewhere in the film Optimus tells Sam that pushing the cube into a transformer's spark would destroy the transformer due to the cube being pure power or much more powerful.

Comment: Nevermind, this is a good tag edit

Comment: @EleventhDoctor, although usually it's a good idea to discuss tag edits on [meta] first. Also be aware not to make too many edits in a row so as not to screw up the front page. [Relevant meta here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9850/how-many-tag-edits-should-we-allow-per-day)

Comment: Thank you for this guidance @Edlothiad, especially about unintended consequences of  a well-intentioned bout of retagging!

Comment: @EleventhDoctor It's just because we want our front page to mainly be questions that are active now. And not random questions that need a big fixing. Although when a very big fix is needed we have our old friend the [Big Edit Event](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10691/the-big-edit-event-is-finished)

Comment: @EleventhDoctor Normally what I recommend is to have at least every other post be yours if you're doing it in bulk. If you have more than 5 in the top 20, wait for a few to cycle out of the way first before continuing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why did Optimus Prime tell Sam Witwicky to push the cube into Primes chest instead of just attacking Megatron with it?

I seem to remember it was somewhere stated that Megatron was (a lot?) stronger/more powerful than Optimus. So Optimus probably deemed it too risky to get the cube anywhere near Megatron where he might actually get hold of it. Optimus basically expected to lose the fight, and if he had to die anyway he might as well destroy the cube to keep Megatron from getting hold of it, and thus save the world.

> Why did Sam choose to ignore his command? Sam had no idea what it would do if it entered Megatrons body, for all he knew it could have made him uber as.

Assuming I remember correctly that Optimus was weaker than Megatron, Optimus would've used the cube straightaway if it really yielded super powers. Since he didn't, Sam probably anticipated Optimus to die a heroic death in the attempt to destroy the cube. Sam assumed that Megatron wouldn't expect him to actually attack using the cube, and therefore used the element of surprise, thus causing the destruction of both Megatron and the cube.